# nodejs script with callbacks and db call never exit

Tags: node.js

I've built a function which sends a list of triggers to a callback :

```
exports.get_triggers = function(_id, result, callback) {
    db.find({ "triggers": {$ne:""} }).exec(function(err, docs){
        var children = Array();
        for(var i=0; i<docs.length; i++){
            if ( docs[i].triggers.id == _id ) {
                console.log(`DEBUG: Trigger found : ${docs[i].name} (${docs[i]._id}`);
                children.push(docs[i]);
            }
        }
        callback(children);
    });
};
```

This is working well in the main program. However, I also need to call `get_triggers` from a script. Here is the way I did this :

```
mylib.get_triggers(job_id,job_result,function(children){
    
    // executing children batchs
    for(var i=0; i<children.length; i++){
        console.log(`DEBUG: triggering job : ${children[i].name} (${children[i]._id})`);
    }
    console.log("DEBUG: end get_triggers");
});
```

This script is executed by bash from a crontab. It gets the list of triggers properly but the problem is that it never exits... and if I add `process.exit()`, the scripts ends before the triggers are retreived.

I would like to understand where is my mistake (`db` is `nedb`) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are experiencing a similar issue, this problem occures because nedb doesn't support concurrent access.

Indeed, the database file was already opened by the main program and I was opening it again through the batch program. As a result, `db.find` never exits because the file is still opened (by the other program).

I finally had to export `get_triggers` and call it by an api call.